# How can I access to Hyper-V management using Linux?

Tags: hyper-v

In my case scenario **example**, this is the Server running the **Hyper-V** virtual machine(s):

```
luis@Fresoncio:~$ sudo nmap 172.18.25.5

Starting Nmap 7.40 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-12-07 22:30 UTC
Nmap scan report for 172.18.25.5
Host is up (0.00039s latency).
Not shown: 997 filtered ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
135/tcp   open  msrpc
2179/tcp  open  vmrdp
49154/tcp open  unknown
MAC Address: 48:43:5A:1E:96:5C (Huawei Technologies)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 57.06 seconds
```

I know the IP of the running virtual machine(s), and I can access to all of them without problems.

How can I **access to the Hyper-V Server** in order to manage it by using Linux?

Both GUI and console methods accepted.

**Further Info** obtained by researching:

- [FreeRDP](http://www.freerdp.com/) is expected to work on Windows (claimed `Update: Now with Windows Server / Hyper-V Server 2012 R2 support.` [here](https://cloudbase.it/using-freerdp-to-connect-to-the-hyper-v-console/)), Linux and MacOS, but the docs about how to use it are not detailed enough for me, and have no examples. Some step-by-step explanation based on my above data example or link to tutorials would be great.

Answer (score 2):

To connect from Linux or Mac OS X using an old version of xfreerdp:

```
xfreerdp –ignore-certificate –no-nego -u "user" –pcb "vmguid" -t 2179 "hypervhost"
```

Newer command tested on freerdp 2.0.0-rc1:

```
xfreerdp /vmconnect:vmguid /u:user /cert-ignore /v:hypervhost
```

user -- user with Hyper-V Administrator rights
vmguid -- GUID for the VM, can be obtained with `Get-VM vmname | select id`
hypervhost -- hostname of Hyper-V server

For more information on using old versions of freerdp:
https://cloudbase.it/using-freerdp-to-connect-to-the-hyper-v-console/

Comment: Not working. And I don't think this will be easy to solve, as long as even Microsoft list incompatibilities between their own Hyper-V Manager versions: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/manage/remotely-manage-hyper-v-hosts . Thanks you anyway.

Comment: i have success with command `xfreerdp /sec:nla /cert-ignore /vmconnect:<vm guid> /d:<domain> /u:<user> /v:<hostname> /port:<port> /log-level:ERROR`